# whats wrong in my nutch recrawl script

Tags: java, nutch

hello i am using this script to recrawl my nutch but it gives an exception ..

```
Indexer: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory file:/home/hat/crawl/indexes already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:772)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1249)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:76)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.Indexer.run(Indexer.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.Indexer.main(Indexer.java:106)
```

script

```
bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls
bin/nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments 
s1=`ls -d crawl/segments/2* | tail -1`
echo $s1
bin/nutch fetch $s1 -threads 100 -depth 3 -topN 5
bin/nutch updatedb crawl/crawldb $s1 


bin/nutch invertlinks crawl/linkdb -dir crawl/segments 

bin/nutch index crawl/indexes crawl/crawldb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*
```

got this from `http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial`

can any one tell me whats wrong....

Comment: The error message `Output directory file:/home/hat/crawl/indexes already exists` seems pretty clear to me, no?

Comment: ya seems to be correct but what is the solution for that,,,,each time i need to delete the directory and index or what???

Comment: Delete or move it. Just don't leave it there.

Answer (score 1):

you are using the same directory for storing the indexes that are generated ie. crawl/indexes. Try to use different one or delete the old ones.